# Applying the divergence theorem to find a trapping region

Tags: dynamical-systems, divergence-theorem

I want to check if my reasoning is correct. The problem is to show that the system

\begin{cases}
\dot x=x-y-x^3 \\
\dot y=x+y-y^3
\end{cases}

has a periodic solution.

In order to apply the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, I need to find a trapping region.

I've already shown that the only fixed point is the origin. So, at this point my idea is to look for an annulus centered on the origin such that the flux of the vector field is positive through the smaller circle and negative through the larger one.

By integrating the divergence in a circle (say C) of radius r I get, after a few computations

\begin{gather*}
\iint_C [2-3(x^2+y^2)]\,dx\,dy=2\pi r^2(1-\frac{3}{4}r^2)
\end{gather*}

which is positive for $r<\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ and negative for $r>\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Does this mean that I can take as a trapping region whatever annulus centered at the origin with radiuses that respectively smaller and greater than $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$? Is this kind of reasoning correct?

Comment: Very similar and similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091328/write-ode-in-polar-coordinates, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542261/unique-periodic-orbit, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842856/how-to-find-a-suitable-function (answer in comments), https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794134/show-that-the-annulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to note that
$$
\frac12(x^2+y^2)'=xx'+yy'=x^2+y^2-(x^4+y^4)
$$
is positive for very small $\|(x,y)\|$ and negative for very large $\|(x,y)\|$.

Comment: Then use that $|x^4+y^4-r^4|=2x^2y^2\le\frac12r^4$ to get quantitative estimates on circles where the derivative is positive and negative.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why do you need that?

Comment: If you want to specifically claim that $1\le r\le\sqrt2$ is a trapping region. However, the inequality is only useful to one side.

Comment: I thought that you were the OP. I still don't get what is the purpose of your remark. Perhaps you don't know that all norms are equivalent? There is no need for anything else than in my answer.

Comment: It gives you $\frac12r^4\le x^4+y^4\le\frac32 r^4$ and thus allows to give guarantees where the radius derivative is positive or negative. As I said, if one wants to give a quantitative statement. For a qualitative statement the reasoning in the answer is enough.